# Select cases if value is greater than mean of group

Tags: select, statistics, spss

Is there a way to include means of entire variables in `Select Cases If` syntax?

I have a dataset with three groups n=20 each (sorting variable grp with values 1, 2, or 3) and results of a pre and post evaluation (variable pre and post). I want to select for every group only the 10 cases where the pre value is higher than the mean of that value in the group.

In pseudocode:

```
select if pre-value > mean(grp)
```

So if the mean in group 1 is 15, that's what all values from group one cases should be compared to. But at the same time if group 2's mean is 20, that is what values from cases in group 2 should be compared to.

Right now I only see the MEAN(arg1,arg2,...) function in the Select Cases If window, but no possibility to get the mean of an entire variable, much less with an additional condition (like group).

Is there a way to do this with Select Cases If syntax, or otherwise?

Comment: Note that not necessarily 10 values will be higher than group average.... If you DO want exactly half of the group (assuming there is always an even number of cases in a group) you should use MEDIAN instead of MEAN.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new variable that will contain the mean of the group (so all lines in each group will have the same value in this variable - group mean). You can then compare each line to this value .

First I'll create some example data to demonstrate on:

```
data list list/grp pre_value .
begin data
1 3
1 6
1 8
2 1
2 4
2 9
3 55
3 43 
3 76
end data.
```

Now you can calculate the group mean and select:

```
AGGREGATE  /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES  /BREAK=grp  /GrpMean=MEAN(pre_value).
select if pre_value > GrpMean.
```

.

Comment: Thank you, that helps! However, I have to do these comparisons for over 50 variables (subscales of pre and post results). Is there a way to do this without having to create a variable for each?

Comment: are you going to select cases by the group means over 50 variables you might be left with an empty dataset?

Comment: you should mark this question as answered and post a new question with a full description of the shape of your data, what you want to achieve and the full process you want to automate